# Tensorflow Matrix Manipulation

Tags: tensorflow

I have below matrix

```
x = [x1, x2, x3
     y1, y2, y3
     z1, z2, z3
    ]
```

and another matrix

```
y = [False, False, True, True, True,  False, False, False
     False, True,  True, True, False, False, False, False
     False, False, False,False,True,  True,  True,  False
    ]
```

I want to create below the new matrix in which x are filled in z the same way True is filled in y, and 0 are filled otherwise.

```
z = [0, 0,  x1, x2, x3, 0, 0, 0
     0, x1, x2, x3, 0,  0, 0, 0
     0, 0,  0,  0,  x1, x2,x3,0
    ]
```

I am able to achieve this by

```
index = tf.cast(tf.where(y), tf.int32)
z = tf.sparse_to_dense(index, tf.shape(y), tf.reshape(x, [-1]))
```

However using sparse_to_dense is complicated and ends up with other issues. Anyone can help with some other way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: [tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) or [tf.scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) might be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

This produces the result using
[tf.scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update).

`tf.tile` just replicates `100 200 300` 3 times so that 3 copies can be filled in the 3 locations.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = [100, 200, 300,
     1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6
    ]

y = [False, False, True, True, True,  False, False, False,
     False, True,  True, True, False, False, False, False,
     False, False, False,False,True,  True,  True,  False
    ]

x0 = tf.Variable( x )

y0 = tf.Variable( tf.cast( y, tf.int32 ))

with tf.Session() as sess :
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    indices = tf.constant( sess.run( tf.where( tf.equal(y0 , True )) ))

     print(sess.run( tf.scatter_nd_update( y0,
                                           indices,
                                           tf.tile(x0[0:3], tf.constant([3])))))
```

output is

```
[  0   0 100 200 300   0   0   0   0 100 200 300   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0 100 200 300   0]
```